# YouTube Player API: Refresh page if video error

Tags: javascript, youtube-data-api

**Solved** this myself and it made me feel silly. What I was looking to do is not properly referenced in the API article. Giving the solution for others looking to achieve this.

**The solution is**:-
I've found the solution myself and boy do I feel silly. It's not referenced correctly in the YouTube Player API.

After many hours of playing with it, here is the solution.

```
// Skip dead videos
function onPlayerError(event) {
  window.location.reload(true); 
}
```

This requires you have the following in the YouTube Player calls:-

```
'onError' : onPlayerError
```

I am loading an array of video id's into the player, sometimes thousands (randomly). I have been trying to figure out a way to reload the page if x video shoots out an error.

The YouTube Player API lists only a couple error codes:-
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Events

However, this does not cover private/copyright videos.

As is when a video ends I reload the page to randomly load a new video with:-

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
    if(event.data === 0) {            
        window.location.reload(true); 
    }
}
```

I have tried the below to no avail:-

```
// skip copyright videos
function onPlayerError(errorCode) {
    if(errorCode == auth) {
        window.location.reload(true); 
    }
}
```

The error code here is what I pulled out of the debug info for a copyright video (its the same for private). However, this is not in the API, thus does not work.

I also tried the following:-

```
// skip by numeric code
function onPlayerError(errorCode) {
   if(errorCode == 100) {
    window.location.reload(true); 
   }
}
```

Which is a valid error code and should work, but doesn't seem to want to.

I've tried a few other methods as well thinking I could read the API info and force a function, seems not. Have also tried fiddling with PlayerState.

Before anyone asks. No, I cannot use playlist embeds.

If anyone could help out, I'd really appreciate it!

Thanks